# flutter redux setState will call oninit function and refresh page again #189

Tags: flutter, flutter-redux

````
Container(
child: StoreConnector<AppState, CollectionState>(
onInit: (store) async {
await loadMoreData(
page: currentPage, extra: {"sorts": sortValue});
},
distinct: true,
converter: (store) {
return store.state.collectionData;
},```

            builder: (BuildContext context, collectionState) {
              collectionProduct = collectionState?.collectionData?.data;
              collectionInfo = collectionState?.collectionData?.collection;
              int totalResults =
                  collectionState?.collectionData?.meta?.pagination?.total;
              return Column(children: [
                _renderCollectionHeader(collectionInfo, totalResults),
                _renderCollectionContent(collectionProduct)
              ]);
            },
````

when i setState, the oninit function will call again ,call api and refresh the page ,how to avoid this

Comment: loadMoreData is a function get data from backend database;

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use setState when you are using redux state, already. Do the changes accordingly.